# Indexed event parameter only returns 1st character in address

Tags: events, logs

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract OwnedI {
    /**
     * Event emitted when a new owner has been set.
     * @param previousOwner The previous owner, who happened to effect the change.
     * @param newOwner The new, and current, owner the contract.
     */
    event LogOwnerSet(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * Sets the new owner for this contract.
     *     It should roll back if the caller is not the current owner.
     *     It should roll back if the argument is the current owner.
     *     It should roll back if the argument is a 0 address.
     * @param newOwner The new owner of the contract
     * @return Whether the action was successful.
     * Emits LogOwnerSet.
     */
    function setOwner(address newOwner) returns(bool success);

    /**
     * @return The owner of this contract.
     */
    function getOwner() constant returns(address owner);

}

pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import "./OwnedI.sol";

contract Owned is OwnedI {
    address public owner;
    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier fromOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the new owner for this contract.
     *     It should roll back if the caller is not the current owner.
     *     It should roll back if the argument is the current owner.
     *     It should roll back if the argument is a 0 address.
     * @param newOwner The new owner of the contract
     * @return Whether the action was successful.
     * Emits LogOwnerSet.
     */
    function setOwner(address newOwner) fromOwner returns(bool success) {
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        require(newOwner != owner);
        address previousOwner = owner;
        LogOwnerSet(previousOwner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return The owner of this contract.
     */
    function getOwner() constant returns(address outputOwner) {
        return owner;
    }
}

    pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import "./Owned.sol";

contract CheckOwner is Owned {

    int public check ;

    function CheckOwner () {
        check = 1;
    }

    function setCheck() fromOwner {
        check++;

    }
}
```

I call setOwner(). When I remove the indexed keyword from OwnerI for LogOwnerSet, I am able to see the parameters in my transaction. However, if I keep the indexed parameter, in my transaction, my event parameters only show the first letter in the address.

Here is with indexed:

```
{
        "topic": "a1d2149652d81eb35c360c115fc7ac594124cb1ea8a5a33e9a7f5768c62869fb",
        "event": "LogOwnerSet",
        "args": [
            [
                "0xc"
            ],
            [
                "0x1"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Here is without indexed:

```
[
    {
        "topic": "a1d2149652d81eb35c360c115fc7ac594124cb1ea8a5a33e9a7f5768c62869fb",
        "event": "LogOwnerSet",
        "args": [
            "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",
            "0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c"
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, it returns just the 1st character of the address. I need the event log to be indexed.

Am testing in remix

**Edit:** I tried this with another Event(address out, bool paused) and transaction log parameter has similar problems. The address returns first char and the bool returns "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" which is true. Am I missing some info on how indexed works?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you're viewing the generated events? When I try very similar code, I'm able to see the full (indexed) address arguments.

Comment: I am using browser remix solidity. When calling a function, you are able to see the transaction that is broadcasted. In the transaction, under the logs sections, you can see any events broadcasted during the call. I have added a screenshot above.

Comment: Got it. I tested via web3.js and saw the full arguments. Perhaps a Remix bug?

Comment: might be, i was testing using javascript vm